# How to use luma classes in custom theme which is inherite form luma?

Tags: magento2

Basically I have created a custom theme  .In custom theme I want to use grid class like `col-sm-3` and `col-md-4` without using **Bootstrap**.

Comment: Than you need to write your custom css code for these classes!

Comment: is there not any way to use the luma classes ?

Comment: As i have seen magneto  use col-m- without using bootstrap.So i am looking for that way